# How handle multiple layouts in android applications

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, screen

I'm a noob in android, and I need some hints to understand how to create simple applications that change layout (for layout I mean what appers on the screen).

Every application has buttons for example that, if pressed, move the app to another layout and here I can do something an then come back (for example the sms app). when layout changes, do I have to start another activity? Or can I do everithing in the main activity? How android does work when I do this kind of things?

Where can I read something about it? do you have tutorials? do you have examples? thanks!!

Comment: What ever you asked are basic things about android app development. [The developer's guide | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) is good to learn basic things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your app. On Android an Activity does much more than showing a hierarchy of widgets, so you may use a single Activity and switch between different layouts or really implement your app as multiple Activities.

Since you are a beginner, I suggest you to write down a new Activity every time your screen is supposed to change layout. Eventually, you'll be able to merge two or more Activity if you think that they are indeed the same piece of functionality

Comment: thanks ! the app i'm developping it's easy, it shows a bitmap on the screen and, if i press the menu button, i go to a new screen where i put my settings. I've seen some tutorial that suggest preferenceActivity.. it's ok?

Comment: i am using that but i got some problems... if you want i have opened a new question about it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127410/android-how-to-pause-threads-during-another-activity/9127510#comment11475505_9127510

sei per caso italiano :) ?

Comment: I answered your othen question, too. Sì :)