# Android - How to pause threads during another activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, draw

I have a thread `"reader"` that reads a file and updates a list A. Another thread `"drawer"` reads what there is in the variable a, do something, calls ondraw and then sleeps for 500ms (during this time reader populates A).

I have also a preference activity that starts if i press menu button.

The problem is that if i press the button while the reader thread hasn't finished to read his file i have en error in logcat.(see below)

I've seen that the problem is the reader thread that is running while it shows me the preference menu, in fact, if i wait until the reader ends and i click on a preference it all goes well, but if i click while its running igot the error.

How can i handle the threads that are still running when i anewactivity starts? how i `"pause"` them? Becouse my file to read can bevery long so i cant wait that reader thread ends.

thanks

EDIT: To be more precise, what appens is that, if i press the menu button, the preferenceActivity starts and i see the correct view (with radio buttons etc) but the problem is when i click on a random point on the screen, it gives me error. If i wait that the read thred ends(i see it from logcat) and then i click on arandom point, it goes everithing well...

logcat error :

```
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): ANR in it.planningpathapp.ale (it.planningpathapp.ale/.Preferences)
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Load: 0.7 / 0.29 / 0.29
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): CPU usage from 13441ms to 36ms ago:
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ningpathapp.ale: 82% = 75% user + 7% kernel / faults: 6211 minor 1 major
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   adbd: 16% = 0% user + 15% kernel / faults: 36 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   system_server: 11% = 8% user + 3% kernel / faults: 229 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   logcat: 3% = 1% user + 2% kernel
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 30 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 52 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 15 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.email: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 41 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 15 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
02-03 10:18:51.196: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): TOTAL: 99% = 72% user + 20% kernel + 1% irq + 6% softirq
02-03 10:18:51.216: WARN/WindowManager(66): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
```

```js
public class PathPlanningApp1Activity extends Activity {


private static Object lock=new Object();

//Mie tag per il debug mediante LogCat
private static final String TAG_readFile = "READFILE_thread";
private static final String TAG_draw = "DRAW_Thread";
private static final String TAG_error = "ERROR";

private final HashMap < Integer , vertex > map = new HashMap < Integer , vertex> ();
private final LinkedList < vertex > originalPath = new LinkedList < vertex > (); 
private final LinkedList < vertex > originale = new LinkedList < vertex > (); 
private final ArrayList < vertex > obstacles = new ArrayList<vertex>();
private final ArrayList < vertex > obstacles_notordered = new ArrayList<vertex>();


private int mapWidth=1;
private int mapHeight=1;

Panel panel;
Resources res;

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Bitmap obstaclesBmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(2, 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

private float zoom=15;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
    res= this.getResources() ;
    panel=new Panel(this);
    setContentView(panel);
    Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "ON CREATE");

}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
protected void onResume()
{Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "ON RESUME");
    setContentView(panel);

    super.onResume();

}
protected void onDestroy(){
    Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "ON DESTROY");
    super.onDestroy();
}
protected void onPause(){
    Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "ON PAUSE");
    Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "stato drawer" +panel.drawerThread.getState());
    Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "stato frt" +panel.frt.getState());

    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.ic_launcher:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(this,Preferences.class);
                                   startActivity(settingsActivity);
                            break;
        case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
        case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon and text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
    }
    return true;
}



class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    FileReaderThread frt=new FileReaderThread();
    DrawerThread drawerThread ;

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        drawerThread = new DrawerThread(getHolder() , this );
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        try{


        int i=0;

        int height=canvas.getHeight();
        int width=canvas.getWidth();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);


        //Log.d(TAG_draw, " obstaclesBmp="+obstaclesBmp.getHeight());
        if (obstaclesBmp != null){
            synchronized(obstaclesBmp){

                canvas.drawBitmap(obstaclesBmp, 0, 0, null);

            }
        }


        }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
            Log.e(TAG_error, "ONDRAW !!Bitmap troppo grossa !dim:"+mapWidth+" "+mapHeight);
        }

        }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(frt.getState()== Thread.State.TERMINATED){
             //frt = new FileReaderThread();                 
               //     frt.start();
        // <-- added fix
             }else {
                Log.d(TAG_readFile," stato frt "+frt.getState());
                frt.setRunning(true);
                frt.start();
             }

        if(drawerThread.getState()==Thread.State.TERMINATED){
            drawerThread = new DrawerThread(getHolder() , this );
            drawerThread.setRunning(true);
            drawerThread.start();
        }
        else{
            drawerThread.setRunning(true);
            drawerThread.start();
        }



    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean retry = true;
        drawerThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawerThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
        retry = true;
        frt.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                frt.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }

    }

}

public class DrawerThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Panel _panel;
    private boolean _run = false;
    Bitmap oldbmp=null;
    Bitmap newbmp=null;
    Bitmap obstaclesBmpTmp = null;

    int i=0;
    int lasti=0;
    int oldW=-1,oldH=-1;

    public DrawerThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }
    public void UpdateBmp(){
        Log.d(TAG_draw, "Update!");
        try{
        int provazoom=7;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int mymapWidth=mapWidth;
        int mymapHeight=mapHeight;


            if(mymapWidth>oldW || mymapHeight>oldH ||oldW<0 || oldH<0 ){

                obstaclesBmpTmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(mymapWidth*provazoom,mymapHeight*provazoom, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 );
                lasti=0;   

                Log.d(TAG_draw, "Cambiate dimensioni! "+oldW+" contro "+mymapWidth+" e "+oldH+" contro"+mymapHeight);
                oldW=mymapWidth;
                oldH=mymapHeight;

            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG_draw, "Dimensioni uguali! ");

            }
            Log.d(TAG_draw, "parto dall'index "+lasti);

            Canvas tmpCanvas=new Canvas(obstaclesBmpTmp);               
            //tmpCanvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            int corrx=-20;
            int corry=10;
            for(i=lasti;i<obstacles_notordered.size();i++){

                    float x=(float)(  ( (obstacles_notordered.get(i).x)    +mymapWidth/2   )*provazoom +corrx  );
                    float y=(float)(  ( (-1*obstacles_notordered.get(i).y) +mymapHeight/2  )*provazoom +corry  );

                    //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "trasformo : "+obstacles.get(i).x+" e "+obstacles.get(i).y+" in  "+x+" "+(-1*obstacles.get(i).y)+"con map w e h"+mapWidth+" "+mapHeight);
                    //Log.d(TAG_draw, "x e y "+x+" "+y);
                    tmpCanvas.drawPoint(x,y, paint);                            
                    Paint prova=new Paint();
                    prova.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    lasti=i;
                    //tmpCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, (float)1, prova);
                }   

        synchronized(obstaclesBmp){

            obstaclesBmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(obstaclesBmpTmp);

        }
        }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
            Log.e(TAG_error, "Bitmap troppo grossa !dim:"+mapWidth+" "+mapHeight);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG_draw, "Drawer Thread Partito");
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    //Log.d(TAG_draw, "Drawer Thread chiama onDraw");

                    //Log.d(TAG_draw, "Drawer Thread ha il lock !");
                    UpdateBmp();
                    _panel.onDraw(c);
                    Log.d(TAG_draw, "Drawer Thread Dorme");
                    sleep(500);
                    Log.d(TAG_draw, "Drawer Thread Sveglio");

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
        //Log.d(TAG_draw, "Drawer Thread termina");

    }


}

public class FileReaderThread extends Thread {
    private boolean _run = false;
    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public double modulo (vertex v){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.x,2)+Math.pow(v.y,2)) ;

    }
    public void insord(vertex dains,LinkedList<vertex> lista){
        //funzione per l'inserimento ordinato in una lista
        ListIterator<vertex> i2=lista.listIterator();

        if(lista.size()==0){
            lista.add(dains);           

        }
        else{
            while(i2.hasNext()){    

                vertex temp=i2.next();

                //System.out.println("x da ins "+dains.x+" confrontata con "+temp.x);
                //if(modulo(temp)==modulo(dains)&& temp.x==dains.x && temp.y==dains.y){ }
                if(modulo(temp)>=modulo(dains)){ 
                    lista.add(i2.previousIndex(), dains);
                    //System.out.println("inserito in posizione "+(i2.previousIndex()));
                    break;
                }
                if(i2.hasNext()==false){
                    lista.addLast(dains);           
                    //System.out.println("inserito in ultima posizione "+(i2.previousIndex()+1));
                    break;

                }       
            }   
        }
    }
    public void insord_x(vertex dains,ArrayList<vertex> lista){
        //inserimento ordinato rispetto alle x per gli ostacoli
        ListIterator<vertex> i2=lista.listIterator();

        if(lista.size()==0){
            lista.add(dains);           

        }
        else{
            while(i2.hasNext()){    

                vertex temp=i2.next();

                //System.out.println("x da ins "+dains.x+" confrontata con "+temp.x);
                //if(modulo(temp)==modulo(dains)&& temp.x==dains.x && temp.y==dains.y){ }
                if(temp.x>=dains.x){ 
                    lista.add(i2.previousIndex(), dains);
                    //System.out.println("inserito in posizione "+(i2.previousIndex()));
                    break;
                }
                if(i2.hasNext()==false){
                    lista.add(i2.nextIndex(),dains);            
                    //System.out.println("inserito in ultima posizione "+(i2.previousIndex()+1));
                    break;

                }       
            }   
        }
    }


    public void run(){
        while (_run) {
            Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Reader Thread Partito");

            //istanzio un oggetto di tipo Resources per usare facilmente le mie risorse dalla cartella Res
            //Resources res = this.getResources() ;

            //Recupero dalla cartella res\raw il file sottoforma di stream e lo trasformo

            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            //Get the text file
            File file = new File(sdcard,"provatesto.g2o");


            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                Log.d(TAG_readFile, "nome file "+file.getName());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d(TAG_readFile, "FILE NON TROVATOOOOOOOO");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //InputStream instream = res.openRawResource(R.raw.provatesto);         
            //DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(instream);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
            String line= "empty";
            int vIndex = 0;
            int oIndex = 0;

            //leggo una linea 


            try {
                //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "leggo il file");

                while((line = dis.readLine()) != null){
                    //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Reader Thread ha il lock!!");
                    //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Ho letto la linea: "+line);
                    StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer( line );
                    //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Ho letto la linea: "+line);

                    try{
                        String entry=st.nextToken();
                        //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Token: "+entry);
                        if(entry.equals("VERTEX_SE2")){
                            Integer index = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                            Double x = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                            Double y = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                            Double r = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());

                            vertex newVertex=new vertex(x,y,vIndex);
                            synchronized(map){ 
                                map.put(vIndex, newVertex);
                            }
                            synchronized(originale){
                                originale.add(newVertex);
                            }

                            if(vIndex>0) map.get(vIndex-1).addEdge(map.get(vIndex));

                            insord(newVertex,originalPath);
                            //Log.d(TAG_readFile, ""+vIndex);

                            vIndex++;

                        }
                        else if(entry.equals("VERTEX_XY")){

                            Integer index = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                            Double x = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                            Double y = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                            //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "xy index: "+x+" "+y);
                            try{                         
                                vertex newVertex=obstacles.get(index);
                            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                                //obstacles.add(new vertex(Double.parseDouble(x),Double.parseDouble(y),Integer.parseInt(index)));

                                if(Math.abs(x)>mapWidth/2) mapWidth=(int)Math.ceil(Math.abs(x))*2;

                                if(Math.abs(y)>mapHeight/2) mapHeight=(int)Math.ceil(Math.abs(y)*2);

                                //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "mapWidth "+mapWidth+"  mapHeight "+mapHeight);
                                /*
                                synchronized(obstacles){
                                    insord_x(new vertex(x,y,index),obstacles);
                                }
                                 */
                                synchronized(obstacles){
                                    obstacles_notordered.add((new vertex(x,y,index)));
                                }


                            }

                            oIndex++;
                        }
                        else {//Log.d(TAG_readFile, "edge");

                        }
                        if(oIndex%200==0){
                            Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Reader thread sta girando");
                        }

                    }catch(NoSuchElementException e){

                    }



                    //Log.d(TAG_readFile, "oindex "+oIndex);



                }//



            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_readFile, "Errore durante la lettura di una linea.");
                line= "end";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG_readFile, "Reader Thread Termina");
        }}



}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you also should not do any long term processing in your UI thread as it may block it and give you the ANR exception. as there is no way to update the UI from another thread it is common to use a `Handler` with either a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` to run the long term processes in the background and update the UI thread.

just look at [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for some explaination and at [android performance](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) for an excellent tutorial on this one.

Comment: thanks! ithink i'm doing that because my onDraw function oly draws a bitmap. that bitmap is generatet in drawer Thread in his run() does:


                     UpdateBmp(); //update the common bmp


                     _panel.onDraw(c);       

              
                     sleep(500);


                    }

Answer (score 0):

To call onDraw I am guessing you are in your UI thread, but it also says you are sleeping in this thread. This is very bad for responsiveness. It appears that your UI thread is locked up and is timing out. Make sure you do any processing/sleeping on threads other than your UI thread.

You can't exactly pause your thread, but you can use a wait/notify condition to halt the thread until your condition is met.

[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1996/jw-04-synch.html) is a quick tutorial on wait/notify to give you an idea.

Comment: thanks! i've tried using wait/notify but if i let the the thread in wait condition and i start the preferenceActivity it gaves me the same error.

to be morespecific i am using the "lunarlander" idea.. so i have a panel class that extends sufraceview and implements surface holder.callback and inside that i create my threads, the drawer thread calls panel.onDraw()

Comment: it looks like you are trying to call onDraw from your extra thread. You can only call onDraw safely from the main UI thread. You either need to wrap your call with a runOnUiThread call or invalidate your Panel to cause it to be redrawn.

Comment: Thanks! how i manage the UIthread? how i put something into its run() ?can you make an example (even pseudocode its ok)

Comment: The UI thread is your main thread. All code runs within this main/UI thread, unless you create a new thread. You can only update UI elements from the main/UI thread.

Comment: these days i've studied e bit but i cant undesrtand something: lets say i have super easy activity...

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Thread mythread =new MyOwnThread();
        mythread.start(); 
                
    }


}

and lets say in the mythread run() i do a lot of calculation but i do nothing like drawing... only calculation.

what i do inside mythread run() it's considered running inside the "main" thread? If yes, how i create a thread outside the main ui thread?

Comment: no, anything that runs in the run method of MyOwnThread is running in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use two separate threads. In fact you only need to repaint when something changes in the file, so you can call `postInvalidate()` from the background thread and in turn this will call `draw()` on the UI thread